# Styling common elements Angular 2+

Tags: angular

What’s the best way to handle global styles for elements such as `ul`, `a` etc.

I don’t really want to have to remember all the different global CSS classes which are available. I also don’t want to add unnecessary markup with components just for a bit of styling on a `ul`.

I find angulars MD / flex-layout takes an interesting approach by using directives to add styles to directives. But with this, I don’t like the idea of the directive holding CSS. I’ve considered using directives to add global classes that way I can keep the SCSS outside of the directive.

What approaches do people take?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some UI library like [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Otherwise, you can use bootstrap, or just as you said before, global scss file.